# Can I use a PNG sequence as an animated material on a SceneKit object?

Tags: ios, animation, 3d, scenekit

I'd like to programmatically change the material of an object rendered using SceneKit in iOS. But I would like to use animated image files. PNG sequences work great in iOS for stuff like UIImageViews -- how do I use them as a material in SceneKit?

Something like this *doesn't* work:

```
floor.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"ANIMATION_" duration:6.0f];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is nothing that you can use out of the box.

I would do this using shader modifiers. If you pack all your images in a single image, you can use a modifier (at the `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry` entry point) to update the object's texture coordinates according to `u_time` so that every *t* ms another image (or sub-image of the atlas) is used.

Comment: Good plan. You might think to use multiple image files and set `contents` on a timer or in an animation block, but don't — using a single image containing all frames and flipping the texture coordinates in a shader is much more GPU efficient.

Comment: Tried this out, but one weird thing is: After a while the image degrades and becomes fuzzy. (In kind of a freakish way.)

Comment: might be due to floating-point precision issues if you continuously increase your UVs. Can you share your code ?

Comment: Shader code: `NSString *shaderCode = @"_geometry.texcoords[0] = vec2((_geometry.texcoords[0].x+floor(u_time*30.0))/7.0, (_geometry.texcoords[0].y+floor(u_time*30.0/7.0))/3.0);";`

Comment: When I change the shader to this it displays wrong, but the jitters appear to stop happening: `@"_geometry.texcoords[0] = vec2(_geometry.texcoords[0].x, (_geometry.texcoords[0].y+floor(u_time*30.0/10.0))/7.0);"`

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by packing images into a single image?

Comment: a "texture atlas" or "sprite atlas". It's a big image with several smaller images pasted inside it.

Answer (score 5):

There is a much simpler solution (or at least I think it's simpler) though I can't attest to whether it's more efficient.  I've tested this on an iPad mini (1st gen) and it works fine.

Rather than place a texture that is a spritesheet into the material's contents (and fiddle with the shader), you can place an SKScene object there instead.

That way you can just use SKSpriteNode objects within the SKScene and animate them using SCNAction objects.  All of the animation can then be controlled easily and more powerfully without having to touch shader code.

```
    NSArray<SKTexture*> *cursorTextures =
    @[
      [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"tilecursor1.png"],
      [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"tilecursor2.png"],
      [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"tilecursor3.png"],
      [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"tilecursor4.png"],
      [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"tilecursor5.png"]
      ];

    SKSpriteNode *cursorSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:cursorTextures[0]];
    cursorSprite.position = CGPointMake(cursorSprite.size.width/2.0, cursorSprite.size.height/2.0);
    [cursorSprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:cursorTextures timePerFrame:0.1]]];

    SKScene *cursorScene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:cursorSprite.size];
    cursorScene.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cursorScene addChild:cursorSprite];

    ...

    self.cursor.material.diffuse.contents = cursorScene;
```

Comment: This does not seem to be very performant but works well enough for me. I haven't done proper performance comparisons to the shader approach though.

Comment: Note that this won't do when dealing with transparency, as `SKTexture`s don't seem to support transparency in images.

Comment: Transparency works just fine if you use PNG or other formats that support it.  Don't use a JPEG if you want transparency.  The code above was lifted direct from my app World of Hex where I use transparency in every one of those images.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.1 / Xcode 9.3 / iOS 11.3**

You can resolve this by rolling your own animation with **CADisplayLink**:

Load your images into an array of **UIImage**

```
var images : [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "image1.png"),
    UIImage(named: "image2.png"),
    ...
]
```

Then, to start the animation:

```
var animationImageFrameIndex : Double = 0
var displayLink : CADisplayLink?

func startAnimation() {
    animationImageFrameIndex = 0
    displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(animationStep(_:)))
    displayLink!.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60
    displayLink!.add(to: .current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
}
```

The preferredFramesPerSecond is the desired rate at which you'd like your **animationStep** method to be called.  However, **CADisplayLink** does not guaranty that it will be called at the rate you request.

The animationStep function gets called periodically by **CADisplayLink**, which actually cycles through the images:

```
@objc func animationStep(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
    let desiredFPS : Double = 24
    let realFPS = 1 / (displayLink.targetTimestamp - displayLink.timestamp)

    material.diffuse.contents = images[Int(animationImageFrameIndex)]
    animationImageFrameIndex += desiredFPS / realFPS
    if Int(animationImageFrameIndex) >= images.count {
        displayLink.remove(from: .current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
    }
}
```

In the method above, **desiredFPS** is the frame rate you actually want to use in the animation.

There is a full sample project on Bitbucket, [here](https://bitbucket.org/drewster77/scenekitimageanimationtest).

You *SHOULD* be able to animate this (a sequence of images) with a simple **CAKeyframeAnimation**, but after much testing, it's clear that doesn't work, which appears to be a bug on Apple's side.  There's an open Radar [here](https://openradar.appspot.com/23283570) from someone else, and I also filed a bug report.